# How do I attach a prefix to each keyword on submit of input field?

Tags: jquery, webforms

I have an input field which when the enter key is pressed (as there is no submit field) I would like javascript to add the @ character infront of each keyword when the form is submitted.

#### For example:

The text would be entered as...

*home, personal, call*

But the value that is submitted would be...

*@home, @personal, @call*

#### So far I have:

```
$("#inputfield").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#inputfield") // Not sure what to add next
        .submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to split the value of the field at spaces and then add an @ in front of each array value, then add that back as the value for the input. Also I recommend listening for the submit event of the form instead of the enter key in the input field.

```
 $('#form').submit( function() {
   var words = $('#inputfield').val().split(' ');
   var newwords = new Array();
   for(i=0, x=words.length; i<x; i++){
    newwords.push('@'+words[i]);
   }
   $('#inputfield').val( newwords.join(' ') );
   //we do not return false because we want the form to submit
 });
```

Comment: +1 this is much better than toying around with keyup/keydown and keycodes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about listening for the submit event rather than using the enter key.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$("#inputfield").keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#inputfield').val($('#inputfield').val().split(',').map(function(item) {
            return '@'+item;
         }).join(',')); 
    $(this).submit();
}
```

Comment: Yours however is smaller and thought me about the map function (which I didn't know about). Thanks for that and the compliment.

Comment: small nitpick, should split/join on ','

Comment: @Deviant, no you shouldn't that will produce: @home,@ personal,@ call